# Subdomain dynamics for blog at nginx and django

Tags: django, nginx, subdomain

I've written a blog service by django
Which users can create for the blog itself
Now the url is as follows.

http://example.com/USER

I want to use the subdomain.
As follows

http://USER.example.com

Show your blog. Without redirecting to the primary url

But I do not know how to do nginx.

thanks

Comment: can you share your current state (share what you've done to solve this issue so others can help you)